# Adding Extraction DateTime in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to write a generic DataFactory in V2 with below scenario.

> Source ---> Extracted (Salesforce or some other way), which don't have
>   extraction timestamp. ---> I want to write it to Blob with extraction
>   Time Stamp.

I want it to be generic, so I don't want to give column mapping anywhere.

Is there any way to use expression or system variable in Custom activity to append a column in output dataset? I like to have a very simple solution to make implementation realistic.

Comment: The need for extraction date embedded inside destination data is for polybase usage. In Polybase it is not possible to read filename as column like USQL.  :(

Answer (score 0):

To do that you should change the query to add the column you need, with the query property in the copy activity of the pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce#copy-activity-properties

I dont know much about Salesforce, but in SQL Server you can do the following:

```
SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as AddedTimeStamp from [schema].[table]
```

This will give you every field on your table and will add a column named AddedTimeStamp with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value in every row of the result.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Unfortunately SOQL doesnt allow CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the column.